# Make Textarea enoug to fit exactly maxLangth attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have different text areas in my form, which have different maxLengths. Therefore, I am trying to size my textares in the beginning so that the max characters can fit there without resizing the box. My first attempt was to fix the amount of columns and then calculate the amount if rows. This works until css comes into play and my textboxes are always to big, because they are wider than the value in columns.

What I am trying to achieve is that the textbox is just big enough to fit the text (not like in the picture).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as far as I know, there is no browser capability for this and then you have a few issues here. You cannot set the `textarea` to a definite height because it heavily depends on the CSS you use and the text you write.

In your screenshot, you do not use a monospace font, that means depending on what your users write, the text will be longer or shorter, even if they use the same amount if characters. Take these 2 examples:

Text 1:

> iiiii

Text 2:

> WWWWW

both of these quotes have 5 letters and have different length if you don't choose to use a monospace font.

If you do use a monospace font the size of your `textarea` still depends on the specific font you use. `Courier` is wider than `Monaco`, I think, just as an example.

Then of course, depending on the width of your `textarea` its height must change.

Back in the day, this problem had to be tackled by JavaScript under the keyword of an auto-resizing `textarea`. There are various techniques for this. Basically what they do is

1. Add a `keydown` event listener to your `textarea`
2. Whenever a user types, use some "magic" to measure your text
3. Resize your `textarea` to fit your text

This would be an example of this: https://codepen.io/vsync/pen/czgrf

Now you can use that example and depending on your specific application only have that execute once on page load with a maximum number of letters, or, if you know the size of the letters of your font already, do some calculations in beforehand and bake (hard code) the sizes (for multiple viewports) in your code.

I think that last thing would be the sanest solution.